# SQLAlchemy accessing column types from query results

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I am connecting to a SQL Server database using SQLAlchemy (with the `pymssql` driver).

```py
import sqlalchemy

conn_string = f'mssql+pymssql://{uid}:{pwd}@{instance}/?database={db};charset=utf8'
sql = 'SELECT * FROM FAKETABLE;'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_string)
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute(sql)
result.cursor.description
```

which results in:

```
(('col_1', 1, None, None, None, None, None),
 ('col_2', 1, None, None, None, None, None),
 ('col_3', 4, None, None, None, None, None),
 ('col_4', 3, None, None, None, None, None),
 ('col_5', 3, None, None, None, None, None))
```

As per [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description) (cursor's `.description` attribute):

> The first two items (name and type_code) are mandatory, the other five are optional and are set to None if no meaningful values can be provided.

I am assuming the integers `(1, 1, 4, 3, 3)` are column types.

My two questions:

1. How to map these integers to data types (like char, integer, etc.)?
2. Are these SQL data types? If no, is it possible to get the SQL data types?

FWIW, I get the same result when using [`raw_connection()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.raw_connection) instead of `connect()`.

Came across three questions along similar lines (which do not answer this specific question). I need to use the `connect()` + `execute()` approach.

- [SQLAlchemy getting column data types of query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258072/sqlalchemy-getting-column-data-types-of-query-results)
- [How to get columns' sql type queried by sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692892/how-to-get-columns-sql-type-queried-by-sqlalchemy)
- [Easy convert betwen SQLAlchemy column types and python data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165143/easy-convert-betwen-sqlalchemy-column-types-and-python-data-types?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If no, is it possible to get the SQL data types?

SQL Server function **[sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)**  could be used to get SQL column's data type directly for provided query:

```
SELECT column_ordinal, name, system_type_name, *
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('here goes query', NULL, 0) ;
```

In your example:

```
sql = """SELECT column_ordinal, name, system_type_name 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('SELECT * FROM FAKETABLE', NULL, 0) ;"""
```

For:

```
CREATE TABLE FAKETABLE(id INT, d DATE, country NVARCHAR(10));

SELECT column_ordinal, name, system_type_name 
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('SELECT * FROM FAKETABLE', NULL, 0) ;

+-----------------+----------+------------------+
| column_ordinal  |  name    | system_type_name |
+-----------------+----------+------------------+
|              1  | id       | int              |
|              2  | d        | date             |
|              3  | country  | nvarchar(10)     |
+-----------------+----------+------------------+
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=19a173fad7735c6b5cfb2cd33e88f469)**

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that the answer would be available in the metadata somewhere, but this is the best I have.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the driver itself.  Below I have almost the same code as yours, just using the pyodbc driver on AdventureWorks.  I picked a table with lots of different datatypes and they are all showing.

```
import sqlalchemy
conn_string = conn_string = f'mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{pwd}@{instance}/AdventureWorksLT2017?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
sql = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM SalesLT.Product;'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_string)
connection = engine.connect()

result = connection.execute(sql)
print(result.cursor.description)
```

Output:

```
(('ProductID', <class 'int'>, None, 10, 10, 0, False), ('Name', <class 'str'>, None, 50, 50, 0, False), ('ProductNumber', <class 'str'>, None, 25, 25, 0, False), ('Color', <class 'str'>, None, 15, 15, 0, True), ('StandardCost', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 19, 19, 4, False), ('ListPrice', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 19, 19, 4, False), ('Size', <class 'str'>, None, 5, 5, 0, True), ('Weight', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 8, 8, 2, True), ('ProductCategoryID', <class 'int'>, None, 10, 10, 0, True), ('ProductModelID', <class 'int'>, None, 10, 10, 0, True), ('SellStartDate', <class 'datetime.datetime'>, None, 23, 23, 3, False), ('SellEndDate', <class 'datetime.datetime'>, None, 23, 23, 3, True), ('DiscontinuedDate', <class 'datetime.datetime'>, None, 23, 23, 3, True), ('ThumbNailPhoto', <class 'bytearray'>, None, 0, 0, 0, True), ('ThumbnailPhotoFileName', <class 'str'>, None, 50, 50, 0, True), ('rowguid', <class 'str'>, None, 36, 36, 0, False), ('ModifiedDate', <class 'datetime.datetime'>, None, 23, 23, 3, False))
```

Are you able to try this driver as a comparison?

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. But I need to use `pymssql`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [PEP249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#type-objects): `type_code` does not look like to be the same through different DB type.

So this answer will be focus on MS SQL Server.

> 1. How to map these integers to data types (like char, integer, etc.)?

You can create a dict of `type_code` to `type_object` using the following code:

```py
import inspect
import pymssql

code_map = {
    type_obj.value: (type_name, type_obj)
    for type_name, type_obj
    in inspect.getmembers(
        pymssql,
        predicate=lambda x: isinstance(x, pymssql.DBAPIType),
    )
}
```

This will produce following dict:

```
{2: ('BINARY', <DBAPIType 2>),
 4: ('DATETIME', <DBAPIType 4>),
 5: ('DECIMAL', <DBAPIType 5>),
 3: ('NUMBER', <DBAPIType 3>),
 1: ('STRING', <DBAPIType 1>)}
```

Unfortunately, I do not have access to a running instance of MS SQL Server. So I am not able to check if type results match with your example.

> 2. Are these SQL data types? If no, is it possible to get the SQL data types?

Looking at the PEP and this result: this fields are not SQL data types. This are "Type Object".

DB API does not look like to provide methods / functions to inspect query results metadata. The API just provide a way to bind data types from SQL to python types.

If you need to get exact SQL data type, then you must write server specific SQL query.

Comment: Thank you, but it looks like this is just the mapping from the code to the data type. I am interested in the SQL data types specifically.